# Texture multiple triangles of a circle in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to center a square texture on a circle using openGL, I have created a loop that fills an array with my circle coordinates, followed by my +/-normals for lighting, finally followed by my (x,y) for the texture coordinates.

For some reason the image ends up kind of smooshed instead of evenly spreading out around the circle.  I'm ot sure if my calculations for the polar to cartesian coordinates are a little off or what.

Below is a section of the code as well as an image of the output.

[image]

```
{
    /*FIX STILL NEEDED TO DYNAMICALLY UPDATE THESE VALUES*/
    //When changing numberOfSides need to also update indices[] to numberOfSides*3 and allCircleVertices[] to numberOfVertices*numberOfSides
    GLfloat x = 0;
    GLfloat y = 0;
    GLfloat z = 0;
    GLfloat radius = 4;
    GLuint numberOfSides = 20;
    GLuint numberOfVertices = numberOfSides + 1;
    GLuint k = 22;
    GLuint angle = 360 / numberOfSides;
    GLushort indices[60];
    
    GLfloat doublePi = 2.0f * M_PI;

    GLfloat* circleVerticesX = new GLfloat[numberOfVertices];
    GLfloat* circleVerticesY = new GLfloat[numberOfVertices];
    GLfloat* circleVerticesZ = new GLfloat[numberOfVertices];
    GLfloat allCircleVertices[420]; /*= new GLfloat[numberOfVertices * numberOfSides];*/

    circleVerticesX[0] = x;
    circleVerticesY[0] = y;
    circleVerticesZ[0] = z;

    //Loop to determine angles between vertices
    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfVertices; i++)
    {
        circleVerticesX[i] = x + (radius * cos(i * doublePi / numberOfSides));
        circleVerticesY[i] = y;
        circleVerticesZ[i] = z + (radius * sin(i * doublePi / numberOfSides));
    }


    //Loop to fill array with vertices
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++)
    {
       
        allCircleVertices[i * 8] = circleVerticesX[i];
        allCircleVertices[(i * 8) + 1] = circleVerticesY[i];
        allCircleVertices[(i * 8) + 2] = circleVerticesZ[i];
        allCircleVertices[(i * 8) + 3] = 0.0f;
        allCircleVertices[(i * 8) + 4] = 1.0f;
        allCircleVertices[(i * 8) + 5] = 0.0f;

        if ((i * 8) + 6 == 6)
        {
            allCircleVertices[6] = 0.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            allCircleVertices[(i * 8 + 6)] = 0.5 * (sin(angle * i));
        }
        if ((i * 8 + 7) == 7)
        {
            allCircleVertices[7] = 0.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            allCircleVertices[(i * 8 + 7)] = 0.5 * (cos(angle * i));
        }
        
        
    }


    //For loop to fill Indices array with correct indices based on number of sides
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSides; i++)
    {
        if (i == (numberOfSides - 1))
        {
            indices[i * 3] = 0;
            indices[(i * 3) + 1] = indices[2];
            indices[(i * 3) + 2] = numberOfSides;
            //cout << indices[i * 3] << ", " << indices[(i * 3) + 1] << ", " << indices[(i * 3) + 2] << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            indices[i * 3] = 0;
            indices[(i * 3) + 1] = i + 2;
            indices[(i * 3) + 2] = i + 1;
            //cout << indices[i * 3] << ", " << indices[(i * 3) + 1] << ", " << indices[(i * 3) + 2] << endl;
        }

    }



 


    const GLuint floatsPerVertex = 3;
    const GLuint floatsPerNormal = 3;
    const GLuint floatsPerUV = 2;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &mesh.vao); // we can also generate multiple VAOs or buffers at the same time
    glBindVertexArray(mesh.vao);

    // Create 2 buffers: first one for the vertex data; second one for the indices
    glGenBuffers(2, mesh.vbos);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vbos[0]); // Activates the buffer
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(allCircleVertices), allCircleVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Sends vertex or coordinate data to the GPU

    mesh.nIndices = sizeof(indices) / sizeof(indices[0]) * (floatsPerVertex + floatsPerNormal + floatsPerUV);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vbos[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Strides between vertex coordinates is 6 (x, y, z, r, g, b, a). A tightly packed stride is 0.
    GLint stride = sizeof(float) * (floatsPerVertex + floatsPerNormal + floatsPerUV);// The number of floats before each

    // Create Vertex Attribute Pointers
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, floatsPerVertex, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, floatsPerNormal, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, (char*)(sizeof(float)* floatsPerVertex));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glVertexAttribPointer(2, floatsPerUV, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, (void*)(sizeof(float)* (floatsPerVertex + floatsPerNormal)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
   
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the `if ((i * 8) + 6 == 6)` cases are supposed to handle and why they only set index 6 and 7?

Comment: I apologize, I  set indexes 6 and 7 to 0.5 and 0.5 because that is the center point of the circle. The first 3 points are the vertices, the next 3 are the normals for the lighting, and the final two are the texture coordinates. 6 and 7 are the center so I make sure they’re set to (0.5,0.5), then repeat the remaining using the formula.

Comment: Ok, get it. `if ((i * 8) + 6 == 6)` is just a strange way of writing `if (i == 0)`. Next: Assuming that you are using the standard implementations of sin/cos, they are assuming radiants and not degrees. `angle` should then probably be `2.0f * M_PI * numberOfSides`? And it should probably be a float/double instead of int.

Comment: Yes, I see that now, that snippet is left over from a previous iteration of the loop that I had prior to this one that was rather messy, I've made the corrections to clean this up and instead just fill ```allCircleVertices[6]``` and ```allCircleVertices[7]``` accordingly.  I attempted changing the angle to a float using ```2.0f * M_PI * numberOfSides``` and it still results in a mish mash of the texture. I do have a feeling that the issue lies in that calculation somewhere.

Comment: @EEngvall: that should be `2.0f * M_PI / numberOfSides` -- i.e. division rather than multiplication.